# Integrate data from one Redmine installation in another one

Tags: redmine, data-migration

Which is the best way to integrate my tickets and other stuff from an old Redmine instance in another one? I've got a Redmine instance in which I already have a lot of data. Now I want to integrate another one into this installation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this plugin](https://github.com/leovitch/redmine_importer). It may help you.

Otherwise, i suggest you to write a `rake` task to do the job. You can get inspired by this task `lib/tasks/migrate_from_mantis.rake`.
The main problem you will face is the correct mapping of foreign ids(users, trackers,...) because your old redmine's ids will overlap your new ones.

- Integrate in first your references (users,...) to get the new ids.
- Export your tickets without references ids (ie user_id,...) but with the label or other field (login or email in case of the users) you can easily find with activerecord methods (`find_by_xxx`).
- Integrate your tickets.

I hope it gives you a good starting point...

Answer (score 0):

another option is to use Task Adapter application, which can transfer tasks (but not comments or attachments): http://www.taskadapter.com/